# Why is sphere with one cross-cap homeomorphic to real projective plane?

Tags: general-topology

From wikipedia [Cross-cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cap),

"A cross-cap that has been closed up by gluing a disc to its boundary is a model of the real projective plane P2 (again with an interval of self-intersection, and two points where this model is not an immersion of P2)."

I am trying to understand what this entry means, specifically what is meant by "model of"? Does the interval of self intersection mean the cross cap glued to a sphere is not homeomorphic to the real projective plane? I think the entry is talking about something else and that the two things are homeomorphic.

Comment: I always think of P2 as a sphere where a point is a portal to the other side. So it is not oriented. This seems like what you a talking about, the cross cap acting as the way to switch sides.

Answer (score 0):

In that article, the cross cap is "imbedded" in 3-space in such a way that the boundary can be pasted to a non-intersecting disk. That is, all the funky business is on the cross-cap side of the pasting. As such, it is not even technically a manifold, as the points where it intersects itself are not locally euclidean. Thus, the closed cross-cap is not a true representation of $P^2$

Another view of the cross-cap, though, is that it is a submanifold of $\Bbb R^4$, and one of the two local surfaces at the intersection is pushed a little way into the 4th dimension. I have not fully reviewed it now, but my memory is that this even takes care of the problem at the two endpoints of the intersection, when done correctly. In this case, the cross-cap is exactly an imbedding of $P^2$ into $\Bbb R^4$.